# Android List View - receive click event on separate item in listview row

Tags: android, listview, click

I have a List View in which I inflate for each item a linear layout. This linear layout contains 2 relative layouts. In each of these 2 relative layouts I included another layout using  so the list will display 2 elements per row. How can I know on which of those 2 elements the user clicked?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem may be resolved if you assign events for both elements. In the getView method of your adapter, you need to assign the clickListener event and set the tag to both views. For instance:

```
        relativeLayout1.setOnClickListener(yourClickListener);
        relativeLayout1.setTag(yourPositionTag);
        relativeLayout2.setOnClickListener(yourClickListener);
        relativeLayout2.setTag(yourPositionTag);
```

This way, you are able to detect which view was selected in your onClick method:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    yourTag = v.getTag();
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.relativeLayout1:
        // your code here
        break;
    case R.id.relativeLayout2:
        // your code here
        break;
}
```

Hope this help!